# How can I use jest cache on gitlab when the test job runs in parallel

Tags: caching, jestjs, gitlab

Our repo to run test using jest takes up to 20 minutes, it can be consider slow.
Now I want to improve the performance for running tests.

currently, we run tests on gitlab, by running

```yaml
  stage: test
  parallel: 4
  script:
    - yarn test:ci --shard=$CI_NODE_INDEX/$CI_NODE_TOTAL
```

After this optimization, it still takes up to 20 minutes to finish the job. So I consider, to use jest cache.

But how can I define the cache key, if use

```
  cache:
    key: '.jest-cache-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_NODE_INDEX}'
```

There will be 4 jest cache for every branch, and many of them in the cache are the same. Because they all contains the transformed npm packages in their cache, and the cache can take much space.

Do you have any good ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think jest cache can be shared between all pipelines, all nodes. The key for the jest cache can just be `test-cache-$CI_PROJECT_NAME`. So this cache can be used everywhere in the same project. The policy should be 'pull-push'.

```
- key: test-cache-$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  paths:
    - .jestcache
  policy: pull-push
```